# How to import github project into android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

May I know how to I import the below project using gradle:

https://github.com/beworker/pinned-section-listview#introduction

Do I have to do it differently using library? If so, please guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
compile 'de.hamm:pinned-section-listview:1.7.0'
```

You can find more info, I think [here](https://bintray.com/davidhamm/maven/pinned-section-listview)

Comment: how about from the original author?

Comment: I didn't found gradle dependency from origin repo. I think they don't support gradle or maven. At least my search gave me no result.

Comment: I see. So how should I include it into my current project?

Comment: I tryied to include this dependecy and it seems that it is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the zip file from github and extract it then open extracted folder in android studio